# Domain keep redirecting to subdomain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I have e codeigniter main domain https example.com and a wordpress installed in directory https example.com/en/

When I try to login in my main domain admin page https example.com/admin I am redirected to https example.com/en/admin/ and respectively if I login correctly I am still redirected to the /en (wordpress). Any help will be appreciated